# UI related code in binding source event or grid event?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-interface

I have a form with 1 bindingsource control.

A grid and several standalone controls (texts and labels) are sharing the binding with this source.

Every time a user changes the grid row i want to enable/disable some controls.

Should i write this code in `BindingSource.CurrentChanged` event or in `DataGridView1.RowValidating` event?

I tend to use the bindingsource event as i think it gives me globally what i want, but i "feel" its wrong to do UI code in there.

Opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not wrong to use `BindingSource.CurrentChanged` evnt to handle UI code. `BindingSource` is a  WinForms component.

The `dataGridView.RowValidating` event fires *before* `BindingSource` event.
Depending an what you need, I'd say it ok to use anyone of them :)